# json.Marshal how body of http.newRequest

Tags: json, go, type-conversion

I'm working to create a little console for managing DigitalOcean Droplets, and I have this error:

> cannot use s (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to http.NewRequest:
> []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

How can I convert `s []bytes` in a good type of value for func `NewRequest`?! `NewRequest` expects `Body` of type `io.Reader`..

```
s, _ := json.Marshal(r);

// convert type

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets", s)                                          
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", token))                                                          
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")                            
response, _ := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: First: check errors and handle them. Second: http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer

Comment: Thanks works! Is very easy

Answer (score 36):

As @elithrar says use `bytes.NewBuffer`

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer(s)
http.NewRequest(..., b)
```

That will create a `*bytes.Buffer` from `[]bytes`. and `bytes.Buffer` implements the io.Reader interface that `http.NewRequest` requires.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are starting with some object, you can just use `Encode` instead of
`Marshal`:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   m, b := map[string]int{"month": 12}, new(bytes.Buffer)
   json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(m)
   r, e := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com", b)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   new(http.Client).Do(r)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json#Encoder.Encode

Answer (score 2):

Use [bytes.NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#NewReader) to create an `io.Reader` from a `[]byte`.

```
s, _ := json.Marshal(r);
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET",
   "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets",
   bytes.NewReader(s))
```